# Haskell loopupKey

Tags: haskell, key

I'm trying to create a function which looks up an ordered list of keys where there is no duplicate keys. Where if the key is not present it outputs "Nothing" or if it is present if it is preset it outputs "Just" and the value an example of this is as follows

```
  lookupKey "a" [("a",1),("b",2)] == Just 1
```

This is what I have so far

```
lookupKey :: Ord k => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v
lookupKey x [] = Nothing
lookupKey x (k,v) 
   | x < k = Nothing
   | x == k
```

I'm stuck on how to complete the rest of the code

Comment: `[[k,v]]` will not work, since `[[k,v]]` is a list of lists of items. Whereas your signature specifies a list of *2-tuples*.

Comment: Hint: what should happen if `x > k`? or `x == k`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If x == k then output the Just value and if x > k then recurse over the function again but check the next value? I'm just not sure on how to implement this is my 2nd week doing haskell and quite struggling

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem has my edit fixed the issue for your first comment?

Comment: no, since that is simply a 2-tuple, not a list of 2-tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the `[[k,v]]` pattern. This is a list of lists where the inner list contains two elements: `k` and `v`. But this is not a 2-tuple.

The pattern should be:

```
lookupKey x ((k, v): kvs)
    | x < k = Nothing
    | x == k = Just …
    | otherwise = …
```

Here `k` and `v` are the items of the first 2-tuple, and `kvs` is the list of the remaining items. So if we call `lookupKey "a" [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]`, then `x` is `"a"`, `k` is `"a"`, `v` is `1` and `kvs` is `[("b", 2)]`. You thus will need to perform some recursion on `kvs`.

I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you I'll try and implement just now